# Android animation offset not working properly on multiple Views

Tags: android, android-animation

I am having multiple TextViews in the same line. I want to use a fade in AlphaAnimation, starting from left to right Views (animation will first start on first item, then on second after offset time etc.)

```
long duration = 1000;
fadeIn.setDuration( duration );
long offset = 0;
fadeIn.setStartOffset( offset );

while (iterator.hasNext()) {    

    textView.setAnimation( fadeIn );
    offset += 300;
    fadeIn.setStartOffset( offset );
}
```

Instead, all of the items start with the last offset (that is, for 5 items, 5*300 milliseconds).

Answer (score 0):

It's because all views are using the same instance of the AlphaAnimation object. You should create multiple instances of your AlphaAnimation, set offsets and assign each animation to a different View.